# CKEditor backspace in IE - When selecting a image and pressing "backspace" causes browser to go back

Tags: ckeditor

When selecting a image and pressing "backspace" it causes browser to go back instead of removing the image.

**Steps to Reproduce**

- Open IE9 browser.
- Go to "http://ckeditor.com/demo".
- Select the image on in the editor by clicking on it.
- Press "backspace".

**Expected Result**

- The image need to be removed.

**Actual Result**

- browser to go back.
  ​

Can anyone have a temporary solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor fix it in version 4.3.1:
[Ticket link](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10055)

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this as well.  Tried with IE9 and sell image.  Type back space =.  Will go back to previous browser page.  Expecting to delete the image.